# Android: unhide a hidden activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a scenario, where I have to hide the Activity initially then after some work flow I have to show the same activity again.
Below is the code I  have tried , it's hiding the Activity properly but didn't showing it again.

```
 this.MoveTaskToBack(true);
 ConnectDevice(); //Connect to a bluetooth device
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(act_existing_asset_collection));
 intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
 this.StartActivity(intent);
```

Comment: what exactly this code is expected to do?

Comment: can you elaborate your requirement ?

Comment: Hi I am connecting to Bluetooth device before that I am hiding the activity , so after pairing completed I have to show the same activity again.

Comment: how does `ConnectDevice()` work? does the code below it execute?

Comment: ConnectDevice() will connect to a Bluetooth device. and that code is working fine.

Comment: does the code below it getting called? `Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(act_existing_asset_collection));` and below.

Comment: Yes it's executing, I can view the activity in minimized state.

Comment: Show the code you have used to show the activity after that.

Comment: intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
 this.StartActivity(intent);

Comment: ok, and does it get called? Are those lines executed? Have you checked with the debugger?

Comment: @Rakesh Hi , using `Finish()` method when need to show previous activity again in `act_existing_asset_collection` activity.

Answer (score 0):

When using **[StartActivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.content.context.startactivity?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9)** , that means Launch a new activity (*The description of the activity to start*).Then current activity will hide in stack of activities . If want to show it again, you can use **[Activity.Finish Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.app.activity.finish?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9)** in the second activity.

As this :  `Finish();` . When press back button in android , actuallly is invoking this method .

About [**singleTop** model](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#ManifestForTasks) when starting `Activity`, there is a **Note** in android official document :

> When a new instance of an activity is created, the user can press the Back button to return to the previous activity. But when an existing instance of an activity handles a new intent, the user cannot press the Back button to return to the state of the activity before the new intent arrived in onNewIntent().